# C# "SendMessage" code error

Tags: c#, vb.net, colors, progress-bar

I needed to convert the following code from VB.NET to C#:

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Enum ProgressBarColor
        Green = &H1
        Red = &H2
        Yellow = &H3
    End Enum
    Private Shared Sub ChangeProgBarColor(ByVal ProgressBar_Name As Windows.Forms.ProgressBar, ByVal ProgressBar_Color As ProgressBarColor)
        SendMessage(ProgressBar_Name.Handle, &H410, ProgressBar_Color, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

VB.NET code source: [Ultimate Programming Tutorials](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2012/12/changing-progress-bar-colors-on-vbnet.html)

I used [developerFusion's online code converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to convert the code, and this is the C# code that it produced:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Form1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    public enum ProgressBarColor
    {
        Green = 0x1,
        Red = 0x2,
        Yellow = 0x3
    }
    private static void ChangeProgBarColor(System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar ProgressBar_Name, ProgressBarColor ProgressBar_Color)
    {
        SendMessage(ProgressBar_Name.Handle, 0x410, ProgressBar_Color, 0);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed "ExactSpelling = true" from the DllImport, as it causes an error.

However, that auto-converted code fails to compile due to the following line:

```
SendMessage(ProgressBar_Name.Handle, 0x410, ProgressBar_Color, 0);
```

The error that is displayed by the C# compiler is:

> Error: The best overloaded method for 'Jyrka98_Modpack_CS.Form1.SendMessage(System.IntPtr, int, int, int)' has some invalid arguments.

It also shows this error:

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Jyrka98_Modpack_CS.Form1.ProgressBarColor' to 'int'

I don't understand what it means by those error messages.  How can I fix that line in C#?

Comment: Just paste the class, seems to work for me.

Comment: Which part, specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you :) Didnt think the converter cares much of the class.

Comment: Also thanks for the -5 !

Comment: @jyrka Don't take the -5 personally.  It's just an indication that this question, as it is currently written, isn't a good fit for this site.  The best way to reverse that score is to edit your question to make it conform better to this site's standards.  You'd never learn what is and what is not a good fit without the up and down votes.  You need to think of it as a learning tool rather than a personal attack.  Some questions are very good, but they just don't happen to be a good fit here.  In this case, you are asking for a code conversion from one language to another.

Comment: @jyrka This should get you started in converting it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Those kinds of questions are typically discouraged.  It might not be a bad question if you understood both languages and you just had trouble with one particular item in the syntax that was tripping you up.  In a case like that, if you asked a very specific question, more along the lines of "what does this mean", and "what is the equivalent", rather than "convert this for me", I think the question would be much less criticized.

Comment: @StevenDoggart This must be like the 4th account for me. Because of the downvotes i cant ask on other account's. I dont take it personally, it's just annoying.

Comment: Then you must not be learning what makes a good question here :)  Have you read through the following help pages?  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, if you need more help in understanding how to improve a specific question, I would recommend asking on the [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) page.  You could ask a question there like "Why was my question down-voted?" and link back to the original question.  Explain why you thought it would make a good question and why you were surprised by the negative response.  That's a great way to get feedback when you don't understand the community standards and you genuinely want to learn.

Comment: @StevenDoggart , I added the message from Visual Studio. And the reason i think it's a good question is because i didn't find anything like this for C# on google. What i did find was that i can change the color, but would have to go back to the Win XP style Progressbar.

Comment: Create the smallest sample of code possible which reproduces the problem.  Post the full VB and converted C# code.  Post the complete error message that you get.  Explain what part of the VB code it is that you don't understand.  Explain what you tried and how it didn't work.  I think if you do all of that, it would be much better received.

Comment: Edit your question here to include all of that info, and then let me know and I'll review it and edit it to improve upon it if necessary.  Then, once it looks good, you can try posting it as a new question.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Is it ok now?

Comment: Those `ChangeProgBarColor` lines at the bottom of the VB code snippet are unneccessary, right?

Comment: @StevenDoggart I deleted those now.

Comment: @jyrka I edited it a bit.  Take a look at my changes.

Comment: @jyrka  See?  If you ask a question the way the community expects, they are actually quite reasonable.  They're reasonable, just very particular :)  Now you actually have some positive reputation points!  Anyway, I hope to see you around in the future.  If you don't understand why the later edits were better received than the original question, let me know and I'll try to explain it as best I can.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I understand a bit why :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart I found the solution. This is what made it not work: "ExactSpelling = true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProgressBarColor` is an `Enum`, which cannot be implicitly evaluated as an `int`.  You will need to cast the value as an `int`.

Try doing the following:

```
SendMessage(ProgressBar_Name.Handle, 0x410, (int)ProgressBar_Color, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show how `ProgressBarColor` is declared, it's a bit of a guess, but since VB is able to automatically convert it to an `Integer`, I'd assume that it's an enumeration.  The VB.NET compiler automatically converts enumeration values to `Integer`, but the C# compiler does not.  In C#, you'll need to explicitly cast the value to an `int`, like this:

```
SendMessage(ProgressBar_Name.Handle, 0x410, (int)ProgressBar_Color, 0);
```

For what it's worth, the proper declaration for the `SendMessage` API call, according to [PINVOKE.NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html), is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

I would recommend using those argument types rather than `int`, like the code converter used.